# Hyperledger fabric 1.2 service discovery not working with TLS enabled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, service-discovery

I am testing the new features in Fabric 1.2 and the service discovery client with TLS is not working properly, without TLS is OK. I took the idea of trying with TLS disabled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631123/hyperledger-fabric-1-2-service-discovery-error).

The command for creating the config file is

> discover --configFile conf.yaml --peerTLSCA crypto-config/peerOrganizations/organizacion1/users/Admin@organizacion1/tls/ca.crt --userKey crypto-config/peerOrganizations/organizacion1/users/Admin@organizacion1/msp/keystore/1fdadd31871470aa56f3779cd9b92e54fdd7745a98fb85975904f1ae03b5ac12_sk --userCert crypto-config/peerOrganizations/organizacion1/users/Admin@organizacion1/msp/signcerts/Admin@organizacion1-cert.pem --MSP Organizacion1MSP saveConfig

It seems correct to me [as in the documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/discovery-cli.html)

The command is

> discover --configFile conf.yaml peers --channel canal2organizaciones --server localhost:7051

And the error is

> failed connecting to localhost:7051: failed connecting to discovery service: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Thanks to [yavcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8211613/yacovm)**
That was the problem actually. I added hostname peer0 to /etc/hosts file and changed localhost to peer0 in the command and everything works fine.

Comment: did you make sure the SAN of the TLS certificate is indeed localhost? 
https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html